# array -> ArrayList при разных типах массивов

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Как преобразовать массив типа int в ArrayList? Насколько понимаю ArrayList не работает с примитивами.

```java
int [] array=new int[5];
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Или есть другие варианты решения?

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1):

```
С помощью стримов - 
int[] array = new int[5];
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

или так:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно массив `int[]` преобразовывать в `ArrayList<Integer>`. Можно получить `IntStream` по его элементам с помощью метода [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-), обработать их и вернуть обратно массив:

```java
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(array)
        // обрабатываем элементы
        .filter(i -> i != 4)
        .map(i -> i * 2)
        // возвращаем массив
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [2, 4, 6, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] array = new int[5];
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i : array) {
    arrlist.add(i);
}
```