# Как достать число из списка, который находится в очереди в java?

Tags: java

```
static void BFS(ArrayList<String> map, int [] s, int [] t){
    int n = map.size();
    int m = map.get(0).length();
    final int INF = (int) Math.pow(10, 9);
    int [][] delta = {{0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}};
    int[][]arrayINFmap = new int[n][m];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            arrayINFmap[i][j] = INF;
        }
    }
    String[][]arrayTFmap = new String[n][m];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            arrayTFmap[i][j] = "False";
        }
    }
    // проблема тут
    ArrayDeque<List> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
    arrayINFmap[s[0]][s[1]] = 0;
    arrayTFmap[s[0]][s[1]] = "True";
    deque.add(Arrays.asList(s));
    while (deque.size() != 0){
        int x = deque.peekFirst().get(0);
        int y = deque.peekFirst().get(1);
    }
}
```

тут проблема в том, что get возвращает Object. А мне int нужен

Comment: Интерфейс `List` обобщенный, почему не используется параметр?

Comment: Какой параметр?

Comment: Прикол в том, что ни в одном курсе на YouTube нормально не работают с очередями. Там просто числа в них добавляют, а потом пару методов показывают. Мне как новичку трудно найти инфу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы *достать число из списка, который находится в очереди в java* требуется как минимум объявить, что очередь содержит списки чисел `Deque<List<Integer>>`, а не нечто "сырое" `Deque<List>`.  Об этом указал в своём комментарии Roman C.

Однако после такого объявления потребуется правильно преобразовать массив примитивных целых чисел `int[] s` в требуемый список.

`Arrays.asList(int[] arr)` НЕ преобразует массив в список, так как он работает только с массивами *объектов*, т.е. как минимум нужно иметь `Integer[]`.

Преобразовать массив в список можно массой способов, см. [array -> ArrayList при разных типах массивов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1189966/), в основном через Stream API:

- Получить экземпляр `ArrayList` при помощи `Collectors.toList()` (Java 8+)
- Получить иммутабельный список при помощи [`Stream::toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList())(Java 16+)

```java
// ...
    Deque<List<Integer>> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
    arrayINFmap[s[0]][s[1]] = 0;
    arrayTFmap[s[0]][s[1]] = "True";
    deque.add(Arrays.stream(s).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())); // Java 8
    while (deque.size() != 0){
        int x = deque.peekFirst().get(0);
        int y = deque.peekFirst().get(1);
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек!